# How to count rows from another table to affect another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables and have been able to get a result of classes that start after a particular time on a certain date.
What I want to do is somehow only show classes that have less than 10 bookings associated.

I have created this sql query to get the classes that a particular user is able to book, but I want to hide the classes where there are already 10 people already booked in the class in question. I.e. the class is full if there are 10 or more associated bookings so I dont want to show these classes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.name
              , a.time 
           FROM class a   
           JOIN class_detail b 
             ON a.class_id = b.id   
           JOIN branch c 
             ON a.branch_id = c.id 
          WHERE c.level <= ( SELECT d.level 
                               FROM client d 
                              WHERE d.facebook_id = 'xxxxxx'
                           )
            AND a.date = '2016-08-17' 
            AND a.time >= '13.00.00';

BOOKINGS
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| CLIENT_ID | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CLASS_ID  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| STATUS    | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> show fields from BRANCH;
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| NAME                | char(50)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| CONTACT_NO          | char(50)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| MAP_IMG_PATH        | char(200)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ADDRESS             | char(200)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LEVEL               | int(2)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| LOCATION            | int(10)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SECTOR_NAME         | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SECTOR_MAP_IMG_PATH | char(200)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+



mysql> show fields from CLIENT;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| NAME         | char(50)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| DOB          | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| LOCAL_BRANCH | int(10)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| FACEBOOK_ID  | char(50)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| START_DATE   | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| EMAIL        | char(50)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PIN          | int(4)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| END_DATE     | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| LEVEL        | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TEL          | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+



mysql> show fields from CLASS_DETAIL;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| NAME         | char(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| DESCRIPTION  | char(200)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CATEGORY     | varchar(4)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ACHIEVE_TYPE | char(200)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| IMG_M        | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| IMG_F        | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+



mysql> show fields from CLASS;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| CLASS_ID  | int(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| BRANCH_ID | int(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| DURATION  | int(3)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| DATE      | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| TIME      | time    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| STATUS    | char(1) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.11 sec)
```

Comment: Can you alter the tables? Would it not be easier to add say a NUM_BOOKINGS field to your Class table and then return only those classes with less than 10 bookings?

Comment: Yes this is possible, i think i normalized the tables a bit to far. This sounds like a good idea. Thank you

Comment: If you are going to add that column, you might also want to create a trigger that would adjust the value when changes are made to the bookings table.

Comment: @TPhe how would I do this, im quite new to SQL and triggers?

Comment: If you are very new, it may not be a great idea to make triggers and change tables around. You should have a good understanding of the functioning of the database before doing that, or you may wind up with unexpected results. I will post a query-based answer below.

Comment: Oh, for info on creating triggers, if you want to go that route, see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: FWIW, I think Dalton D's suggestion is a poor one. I would however store date and time as a single entity.

Comment: @Strawberry I'd love to hear your suggestion. OP said he's a newer sql programmer so I thought it easiest to suggest a simple table change. Of course he can use a 20 line select statement like TPhe answered with, but that won't help him since he won't understand such complex logic yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this without making changes to your tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.name
              , a.time 
           FROM class a 
           Inner join (SELECT class_id, count(clientid) 
                       FROM bookings 
                       GROUP BY class_id
                       HAVING count(clientid) < 10) as openClasses on        
                a.class_id = openClasses.class_id
           JOIN class_detail b 
             ON a.class_id = b.id   
           JOIN branch c 
             ON a.branch_id = c.id 
          WHERE c.level <= ( SELECT d.level 
                               FROM client d 
                              WHERE d.facebook_id = 'xxxxxx'
                           )
            AND a.date = '2016-08-17' 
            AND a.time >= '13.00.00';
```

This query uses a derived table, which I called "openClasses". The point of the table is to get the class_ids of the classes that have less than 10 bookings. This table is then inner joined to restrict results to only this set of classes.

It may be that you have to add a where clause into this derived table to restrict to only certain statuses.

Comment: This just needs a little reworking to make the field names capitals and there was an error near Group by. Other than that it works great. Many Thanks